# jQuery code stop excuting after Ajax call returned

Tags: jquery, loading

i just try to set up admin zone with dynamic database controlling. its working quite nice and i have setted up the add, delete and update records. the issue is when i run the code first time everything is just ok! i mean, if i want to delete record, i press it once and it remove. but then i cant remove another records and i have to refresh my whole page to do it again (opening the database again and so)

here my code:

```
//------------------------ loading manage area -----------------------------
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sitesAddForm').hide();
    $('#select_table').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val(); //is calling to the value of the options from the dropdown menu and so i can select between the tables of the database.
//-------loads forms when database changeing------
switch (val)
    {
    case 'sites':
        $('#sitesAddForm').show();

    case 'graphic':             
        $('#sitesAddForm').hide();
    }   
//---
//---------loads the database---------
$.post('manage_query.php', {value: val}, function(data){
        $('#displayer').html(data);
        //-------------------------------deleteing&updating zone----------
        $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var siteID = $(this).attr("id");
        $.post('manage_query.php', {siteDelete: siteID, value: 'sites'},
        function(deleted){
            $('#displayer').html(deleted);
        });
});
```

its just part of the code but the issue fall here, after the last line the

```
 $('#displayer').html(deleted);
```

is excuted, the code not working anymore. but i still can see the results.

the php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['siteDelete'])){
    $siteDelete = $_POST['siteDelete'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM sites WHERE id=$siteDelete");
    echo 'Site deleted successfully';
}
```

all the resulets are just written into one html div with the id of "displayer"

i hope i made it all clear